# Why does a method call to this function slow my thread? (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I am making a Conway's Game of Life program using java swing, and running it in the BlueJ IDE. I have a separate thread which runs the rules for the game, using swing worker. I created a method to check how many selected squares are around a specific cell.

**Whenever I run the program with the checker method** (below)**, the code takes an excessively long time to execute. However, when I don't call the method, the code runs very fast.**

**Two questions:** **1)** Why does this happen? **2)** How can I run the method without slowing it down?

Here is my code.

```
private SwingWorker<ArrayList<Integer>, Object[]> createRunnable() {
        swingWorker = new SwingWorker<ArrayList<Integer>, Object>() {

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<Integer> doInBackground() throws Exception{
                ArrayList<Integer> aiden = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                Object[] objects = new Object[2];
                while(running)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < square;i++)
                    {
                        for(int j = 0; j< square; j++)
                        {

                            aiden = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList((w/square) * j,(h/square) * i,(w/square),(h/square),i,j));

                            publish(aiden);


                            try{
                            Thread.sleep((long)5);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                           throw e;
                        }


                        }
                    }





                }
                return aiden;
            }
            @Override
            protected void process(List<Object> chunks) {
                ArrayList<Integer> aiden = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                aiden = (ArrayList<Integer>)chunks.get(0);
                int j = aiden.get(5);
                int i = aiden.get(4);
                ArrayList<Integer> selec = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(aiden.get(0),aiden.get(1),aiden.get(2),aiden.get(3)));
                System.out.println("Hi");

                if(selected.contains(selec) || surround(selec,i,j) == 0)
                               { 
                                selected.remove(selec);

                                repaint();
                            }
                repaint();   
            }

        };
        return swingWorker;
    }
```

```
 public int surround(ArrayList<Integer> j, int x, int y)
    {
        int count = 0;

        for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
        {
         for(int k = -1; i <= 1; k++)
         {

             if(selected.contains(Arrays.asList((w/square) * (x + k), (h/square) * (y+i), (w/square),(h/square))))
             {
                 count+=1;
                }
            }
        }


        return count; 

    }
```

Comment: repaint in doInBackground is a mistake, place it in progress method override

Comment: That is one very tight animation loop, and in fact unrealistic too tight.

Comment: What does the "progress method" in swing worker do? Why is it bad to call repaint in my doInBackground method?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I increased the sleep time, it didn't solve my problem

Comment: We would need a [mcve] I think to adequately address this question. Note that your process method is not a true override -- place an `@Override` annotation above it to see -- since it does not have the right parameters